# How do I read the SelectedValue of a DropDownList in code behind, when the option has been added using JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net

How do I read the SelectedValue of a DropDownList in code behind, when the option has been added using JavaScript?

A little more background: I have cascading drop down lists, and I would like to fill in the values using JavaScript, so that I avoid postbacks when the user changes the selection in the first drop down list.

I am not allowed to use an Update Panel.

I have build a simple demo demonstrating problem. Here is my markup code:

```
<p>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="FilterDropDownList" />
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SearchButton" Text="Search" 
        onclick="SearchButton_Click" /><br/>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="QueryTextBox" />
</p>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var filterDropDownListId = '#<%= FilterDropDownList.ClientID %>';

        $(filterDropDownListId).append($('<option>').prop('value', 'Alpha').html('A'));
        $(filterDropDownListId).append($('<option>').prop('value', 'Beta').html('B'));
    });
</script>
```

And in the code behind I have the following:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // Register the allowed values for the down down list.
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(FilterDropDownList.UniqueID, "Alpha");
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(FilterDropDownList.UniqueID, "Beta");

    base.Render(writer);
}

protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(
        String.Format("{0}?dropdown={1}&query={2}",
            Request.Url.AbsolutePath,
            FilterDropDownList.SelectedValue,
            QueryTextBox.Text));
}
```

The problem is, that FilterDropDownList.SelectedValue is empty. I would have expected it to be either "Alpha" or "Beta". I can read the value of QueryTextBox.Text without problems.

It is possible to read MyDropDownList.SelectedValue when the values have been populated using JavaScript? Or do a have to use a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write the selected value to a hidden textbox with javascript and read the value in the code-behind.

Comment: But is that really necessary? It just seems weird since I have to register the possible values using RegisterForEventValidation to avoid a security error.

Comment: I agree 100%. That's why I added your question as a Favorite.:) I want to see if it possible. If this is a problem that is stopping your development you can "work around" the issue by implementing my suggestion and if you end up getting a satisfactory answer from the community then go back and implement that one.

Comment: I will leave the question unanswered for a couple of days, and hope for an explanation. If nothing comes up, I'll give you credit for the correct answer. :)

Comment: I ended up creating the drop down menus as <select> elements without runat="server" on them. That way I don't have to use the hidden fields and I don't have to register allowed values for the validation. Old school, but it works fine.

Comment: So basically the answer is that it is not possible? Strange. Another sleepless night for me then ....